# HTML5 drop logic to prevent a move and allow copy?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a web page that has a drop target, on which I can drop text or local files.

If I drag and drop content from some applications that allow moves (example: Microsoft Excel or Notepad++) then the content disappears from the drag source.

I don't want that, I only want to receive a copy of the data.

I've tried intercepting [dragenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragenter_event) and setting `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"` but it doesn't stop the drag source from deleting its content.

Any suggestions? I don't have a quick standalone HTML I can post at this time but will update my question if I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was close! It looks like you have to set `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"` in the `dragover` event. This works. (and automatically changes the cursor for feedback.)